# how to return list of list in c#?

Tags: c#, json, list

I am working on web api.I am getting data from one table.

Data from database

```
DispatchData dta = new DispatchData();
using (SalesDataContext oSqlData4 = new SalesDataContext())
            {
                // amount paid -- not paid

                var Amount_Paid = (from x in oSqlData4.Finances
                                   where 
                                 (x.Order.Customer_ID.Equals("190") ||
                                  x.Order.Customer_ID.Equals("1334"))
                                   where (x.Status == "Not Approved")
                                   select x).ToList();
                foreach (var item in Amount_Paid)
            {
                
                dta.data = new string[] { item.Order_ID.ToString(), item.ID.ToString() };
            }
               var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dta);
        
                return json;
              }

public class DispatchData
    {
        public string[] data ;
        
    }
```

its returning me  only one record

```
{"data":["2508","4684"]}
```

I want each row in array like this

```
{"data":[ ["2508","4684"],["2508","4684"],....] }
```

Comment: Why not just parse the data as JSON and return that instead of a List<List<String>> ? Your desired output is not a List<List<String>>. It's already in a JSON/dictionary format. You also haven't told us what your current output is, so it can be compared to the desired output. We can't really make assumptions about your data.

Comment: how can i put my querry output in data object.
like this { "data": [ [ "item1", "item2", "item3" ] ] }.assume items are from db

Comment: i edited the question please check it now

Answer (score 0):

There's really not enough information in the question for a full answer, but with a few assumptions...

Assuming the `SalesDataContext` query returns an object, let's call it `SalesPerson`:

```
SalesPerson
    Name (string)
    Title (string)
    Location (string)
    Id (int)
    Date (DateTime)
    Sales (decimal)
```

With the above assumption, you can simply select each property as a string from the query result and throw it into an array:

```
var myList = Amount_Paid.Select(x => 
                new[] {
                    x.Name,
                    x.Title,
                    x.Location,
                    x.Id.ToString(),
                    x.Date.ToString(), // add a format as needed
                    x.Sales.ToString() // add a format as needed
                }
            ).ToArray();

return myList;
```

If you *Really* want a `List`:

```
var myList = Amount_Paid.Select(x => 
                new List<string> {
                    x.Name,
                    x.Title,
                    x.Location,
                    x.Id.ToString(),
                    x.Date.ToString(), // add a format as needed
                    x.Sales.ToString() // add a format as needed
                }
            ).ToList();

return myList;
```

The result can then be serialized as needed.

## Edit

Based on the OP's edit, not much changes with the assumptions above. However, the OP's edit has two errors.

1. The `foreach` loop is overwriting `dta.data`.
2. The signature of `data.data` should be `string[][]`, not `string[]`.

#### Incorrect

```
public class DispatchData
{
    public string[] data ;        
}

foreach (var item in Amount_Paid)
{
    dta.data = new string[] { item.Order_ID.ToString(), item.ID.ToString() };
}
```

#### Corrected

```
public class DispatchData
{
    public string[][] data;        
}

# can either predefine the size of the dta.data array, 
# or just assign once the property can be materialized. 
# Let's use the latter...
dta.data = Amount_Paid.Select(x => 
             new[] {
                 item.Order_ID.ToString(), 
                 item.ID.ToString()
             }).ToArray();
```

Comment: please check edited question .

Comment: @Roma - edited the answer. Between my initial answer and the edit, you should have enough to get you in the correct direction. Please read through everything I posted; the original answer was enough to answer your question, but it almost seems like you are wanting us to write your code for you. Please feel free to ask any clarifying questions, but I'm not going to write all of your code ;)